# Proving axiom 1 of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I am doing one of the problems in my book, but I am uncertain if my approach is correct.

Problem: $(u,v)=-u_1u_2u_3$

Let $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$,
$v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$.

\begin{align}
(u,v)&= u_3u_2u_1 \\
     &= (v,u)
\end{align}

Axiom 1 proved. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you list the axioms so we know which is "axiom 1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally incorrect.

It's a function with two arguments that is defined here: $(u, v):=-u_1u_2u_3$.
Putting in $x,y$, we get $(x,y)=-x_1x_2x_3$.
Putting in $v,u$, we get $(v,u)=-v_1v_2v_3$.
Now we can easily show up two specific vectors $u, v$ such that $(u, v) \ne (v, u)$.